# Google spreadsheet script function call

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a form in Google docs. I have script that form for a column auto increasing for every entry and another function to check whether the current entry have a similar entry or not. codes are given below.

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var row =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(row,7).setValue('sn'+(row-1));
}

function removeDuplicates() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var newData = new Array();
for(i in data){
var row = data[i];
var duplicate = false;
for(j in newData){
if(row[1] == newData[j][1] && row[2] == newData[j][2]){
duplicate = true;
}
}
if(!duplicate){
newData.push(row);
formSubmitReply();
}

}
sheet.clearContents();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

as you you can see the 1st function is for auto increasing a column and the 2nd one for checking the duplicate entry. I can trigger them differently but what I want to do is that, to call the 1st function in the 2nd function as well, so that while i trigger the 2nd function submitting the form, that automatically run the 1st function in it. How can I do that??

Note: Simple call like `onFormSubmit()` didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Factor out the code you want to run from multiple locations. Instead of doing this:

```
function eventHandler(e) {
   // code to increase column
}

function otherFunction() {
   // code to remove duplicates
   eventHandler(e);   // won't work, e is undefined!
}
```

You could do this:

```
function tinyHelperFunction() {
  // code to increase column
}

function eventHandler(e) {
  tinyHelperFunction();
  // other stuff, maybe
}

function otherFunction() {
  // code to remove duplicates
  tinyHelperFunction();
}
```